# Acra Package is not a constant error (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, crash-reports, acra

I am trying to use Acra in my app and i am running into following issue. I tried to check the source code of Acra but still cannot figure out the issue. I couldn't find anything else on Google. Now i am stucked on this for last two days. I know it should be something very simple but i am not able to see it. I feel an extra pair of eyes may help me on this.

```
03-13 12:52:37.588      332-332/? D/ACRA﹕ ACRA is enabled for com.myapp.application, intializing...
03-13 12:52:37.598      332-332/? D/ACRA﹕ Looking for error files in /data/data/com.myapp.application/files
03-13 12:52:37.598      332-332/? D/ACRA﹕ Looking for error files in /data/data/com.myapp.application/files
03-13 12:52:37.608      332-332/? V/ACRA﹕ About to start ReportSenderWorker from #checkReportOnApplicationStart
03-13 12:52:37.608      332-350/? D/ACRA﹕ #checkAndSendReports - start
03-13 12:52:37.608      332-350/? D/ACRA﹕ Looking for error files in /data/data/com.myapp.application/files
03-13 12:52:37.608      332-350/? I/ACRA﹕ Sending file 1f0d91c8-ca49-4de3-82ac-236d6337a2d1.stacktrace
03-13 12:52:37.618      332-350/? E/ACRA﹕ Failed to send crash reports for 1f0d91c8-ca49-4de3-82ac-236d6337a2d1.stacktrace
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Package is not a constant in org.acra.ReportField
            at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:198)
            at org.acra.CrashReportPersister.load(CrashReportPersister.java:264)
            at org.acra.CrashReportPersister.load(CrashReportPersister.java:75)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:140)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
03-13 12:52:37.618      332-350/? D/ACRA﹕ #checkAndSendReports - finish
```

This is my application file

```
@ReportsCrashes(
 formKey = "",
 mailTo = "myemail@anoviceguy.com",
 reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
 mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
 forceCloseDialogAfterToast = false, // optional, default false
 resToastText = R.string.error_something_went_wrong,
)
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ACRA.init(this);
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
}

}
```

Comment: Post your ACRA config. ie the annotations for Application class.

Comment: @William I have added my Application file here. It is fairly simple right now, just sending the error logs as email. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, while reading a previously generated crash report it has come across a a chunk of data 'Package' that it believes is an instance of ReportField. But there is no ReportField.PACKAGE so it crashes.

There are 2 possible reasons for the crash.

1. The generated crash report is corrupt.
2. You previously had config that specified a bespoke list of fields to output that included a field called 'PACKAGE' and ACRA added the field with no data (because it doesn't understand that field).

In either case the solution is to clear the data for app.
In the second case then arguably ACRA could do a better job writing the crash report such that invalid config is ignored in a better fashion. Log an issue with ACRA.